# Draw a polygon in python using a function f(n, r)

Tags: python

I am having trouble drawing an octagon in python by creating a function: f(n, r) with n number of  sides and r, the length of the sides.

Comment: Have you tried the `turtle` package to program the drawing of the polygon?

If what you need is to draw the polygon using static geometric objects like those in `matplotlib`, you should post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution, using `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def draw_polygon(n: int, r: int=1) -> dict:
    """Draw a regular polygon with `n` sides, each with size `r`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        Number of sides of the polygon.
    r : int, default=1
        Size of the polygon sides.

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        Dictionary with the x and y coordinates of the polygon.
        Dictionary keys:
            * `"x"`: the x-coordinates of the polygon.
            * `"y"`: the y-coordinates of the polygon.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If `n` is smaller than 3.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> draw_polygon(4, 1)
    {'x': [0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0], 'y': [0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]}
    """
    if n <= 2:
        raise ValueError(
            f'`n` must be an integer greater than 2, not {n}'
        )
    angles = int(360/n)
    xf = [0, 0]
    points = {'x': [0], 'y': [0]}
    for angle in range(0, 360-angles+1, angles):
        xi = xf
        xf = [
            xi[0] + r * math.cos(angle * math.pi / 180),
            xi[1] + r * math.sin(angle * math.pi / 180),
        ]
        points['x'].append(xf[0])
        points['y'].append(xf[1])
    points['y'][-1] = points['y'][0]
    points['x'][-1] = points['x'][0]
    return points


def plot_shape(n: int, r: int=1, **plot_kwargs):
    """Plot a regular polygon with n sides of length r.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        Number of sides of the polygon.
    r : int
        Length of each side of the polygon.
    plot_kwargs : dict
        Keyword arguments to be passed to plt.plot.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> plot_shape(3, 1)
    >>> plot_shape(4, 1, color='red')
    >>> plot_shape(5, 1, color='red', linestyle='dashed')
    """
    shape = draw_polygon(n, r)
    plt.plot(shape['x'], shape['y'], marker='o', **plot_kwargs)
    plt.show()
```

### Examples

**`plot_shape(3, 2)`:**

[image]

**`plot_shape(4, 2)`:**

[image]

**`plot_shape(5, 2)`:**

[image]

**`plot_shape(6, 2)`:**

[image]

**`plot_shape(7, 2)`:**

[image]

**`plot_shape(8, 2)`:**

[image]